# Stibo Step Search Business Rules

Tags: master-data-management

Is there a way to search text in all business rules in the Stibo Step product?

I have inherited a project and I'm trying to track down all the places an attribute is used. I have a attribute `VA-1` but we have business rules that gives it a default value in an array.  Instead of using the actual attribute, it is `"VA-1"` so it is not shown as a reference for the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Step search screen you can select JavaScript Search.

It not an obvious drop-down but the triangle next to the word `Search` will open a drop-down menu and you can select `JavaScript search`.